# Stripe and Webform?

Tags: civicontribute, webform-civicrm, stripe

CiviCRM 5.7.5, Drupal 7.63, Webform Civi integration 7.x-4.18

I've been trying to get Stripe to play nicely with Civi Webform but thus far I've not had any luck... what appears to me to happen is that Stripe packages/obscures the card number before the form itself gets processed (which I would of course expect), but then the form views the number as an invalid card number and requires reentry of it.  I've confirmed that Stripe does work correctly on a standard contribution page but I really would like to get this working in a webform, and it appears that others have successfully done so.  Would anyone have insight into what I might be missing?

Answer (score 2):

You’ll need to update your webform civicrm module. You are a few versions behind

Matt Wire did some work to make Stripe work with Webform CiviCRM  and I merged it - 120% sure it will work for you.

Comment: Thank you - are you able to confirm whether Stripe should theoretically work in a webform?